# Can you define an Android intent-filter using a string resource?

Tags: android, string, resources, intentfilter

I wanted to define the string name of my intent in the `strings.xml` file, and then bind that string to an intent filter, as so:

```
<intent-filter >
    <action android:name="@string/app_intent" >
    </action>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
    </category>
</intent-filter>
```

When i tried this however, i get various errors about the system could find no activity to handle my intent. I was trying to keep values (ie, the intent names) centralized instead of hard-coded in the manifest as well as in code. As it is, at least this lets me centralize it out of the application code, but i still have it hard-coded in the manifest.

Is this really impossible to do or is there some way to make it work?

Comment: Interesting question. What happens if you remove the "" from around `@string/app_intent`? I'd expect a build error but it might be worth a try.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would you *expect* this to do? Resources can vary with the device configuration - everything from landscape vs. portrait orientation to screen size to current language. You wouldn't want the intent action to vary with these parameters.

Comment: @MisterSquonk, thanks for the suggestion, but yes, as you expected, it throws an exception, specifically a `Parser Exception`. Thanks though.

Comment: @adamp, I expect it to replace it with my intent name. My activity is still responding to the same intent, regardless of how the activity's layout may change or now for different configurations. Eg. an email app would still respond to a hypothetical `SendEmail` intent regardless of screen size or orientation.

Comment: @adamp: In a practical sense, string resources aren't affected by orientation changes. Also, if the default `/res/values/strings.xml` file contained the 'intent' strings, then the localized 'values' directories wouldn't need them. In other words if (on a device set for French, for example) `/res/values-fr/strings.xml` doesn't contain a particular string resource, Android will fail-over to `/res/values/strings.xml` at runtime.

Comment: @eidylon: Worth trying but, I suspect, this is a design aspect of how the manifest works and unfortunately I think you're out of luck on this one. Nice idea though.

Comment: @MisterSquonk - Kinda stinks. Would be nice to completely eliminate the hard-coded values. And I had *figured* it should work given that you can do the same thing for the `android:icon` and `android:label` attributes of the `application` node. *sigh*

Comment: @eidylon: Agreed. It seems to be an oversight as I can't think of a practical reason for not allowing it. Oh well!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its not the issue with intent-filter, the issue is with `android:name`. `android:name` attribute is not taking string resource for activity name also. example `<activity android:name="@string/app" android:label="@string/app_name">` is not valid in android.

Comment: It is **specifically** the `android:name` attribute, or is it limited to the activity nodes? Because the other one, the `android:label` **does** take resource ID's as such, at least on the `application` node of the manifest.

Comment: Well, I'm not exactly sure where the limitation lies, as some attributes in the manifest DO in fact support this method. But apparently this one, for whatever reason, does not.

Comment: What *is* valid if you want to use a String?

Answer (score 5):

Not directly answering the OP's question, but what drove me to this question was that I wanted to be able to define different actions in different situations (including defining an action triggering a component in android library in the application using this library). I eventually found about [manifest placeholders](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables), which were actually what I needed. Hopefully, this will be useful for someone else too.

PS: Yes, defining a placeholder in the app still allows you to use it in a library, because of the manifest merging happening at build time.